# Why do I get syntax error when converting with UFormat in Powershell

Tags: powershell

Why can't I convert this date to Unix DateTime : I got a syntax error with

```
([DateTime]"2015.08.24 09:10") -UFormat %s
```

What is the right syntax ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`UFormat` is a `Get-Date`'s cmdlet parameter, not a standalone operator. Try this:

```
 Get-Date '2015.08.24 09:10' -UFormat %s
```